# Network communication without a centralized host. Is it possible?

Tags: networking, tcp, udp, communication

I have a server and a few clients, software-wise, and I want the client to figure out the IP address of the server without actually referring to a specific database.

I had a misconception about UDP up until now that UDP only used the Port as a common identifier between servers and clients, but I was wrong apparently.

**Requirement:**
I want my server to broadcast a message to ALL devices on the network, once every 5 seconds or so.
That message will contain the IP of the server.

**Software using such technique already:**
A photo transfering app for iOS, called "Photo Transfer App" is really easy to use because it basically tells you to open the app on your Mac and on your iPhone, and then you press "Discover", and BAM! your devices have found each other.
But how?

How can my requirement be achieved?

**EDIT**
I googled a bit. Could server host on `255.255.255.255`and clients connect to that address solve my problem?

[According to this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broadcast_address), `255.255.255.255` is used for broadcasting.

Can someone confirm?

Comment: what you want is impossible. the client has to talk to SOMETHING to get information about where the server is, or it has to scan the network until it finds the server. in other words, you need SOME kind of network database to provide the required information. dns `TXT` record, dhcp option, blah blah blah. You dont want clients starting broadcasting "yohooo, here I am", as that'll just flood the network with useless traffic.

Comment: @MarcB please read my question again, I have added some additional info.

Comment: You can't really use a device (client or server) assigned to `255.255.255.255` since sending to that address will interrupt _every device_ on a network (printers, routers, switches, PC not participating, etc.). Also, if you ever want to use IPv6, too, you will have a problem since broadcast doesn't exist on IPv6. You should really look into multicast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you will use broadcast address (255.255.255.255) or network broadcast (like 192.168.1.255 for network 192.168.1.xxx or in the prefix notation 192.168.1.0/24). You will get essential limitation: your broadcast will NEVER leave that network. So all host inside the LAN will see your broadcast message but nobody else.

Multicast as mentioned by null is better because it can leave your network and pass through the IP routers. But this is feasible only by special network settings on that routers (and require multicast routing capability on that routers).

Another technology without such limitation can be use is dynamic DNS (server will register itself via DNS).

Comment: So if I want to broadcast to ALL devices within my home network ONLY, the address `255.255.255.255` is acceptable to use?

Comment: @vaid it okay only if your home network consist of only one IP network. If you have two networks (ex: 192.168.1.xxx and 192.168.2.xxx with router between them) it will not work.

Comment: @DmitryPoroh Multicast does not go over the internet. Broadcast can be configured to go over multiple subnets. 192.168.0.255 will stay in the same subnet though. Broadcast is deprecated. It doesn't exist in IPv6.

Answer (score 1):

[Multicast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_multicast) would be better than broadcast. See also: [Bonjour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonjour_(software)), [multicast DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_DNS) & [SSDP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Service_Discovery_Protocol).

More information on Bonjour is [available here](https://developer.apple.com/bonjour/).

Comment: Ok, great. I just tried to make my server host UDP on address `255.255.255.255` and I could successfully receive a message sent from my Mac. My server normally has its IP set to `192.168.1.27 ` so this is what I'll use I think since all communication will take place from within the local network. Are the any security issues with my approach?

Comment: This is exactly what Bonjour is for. [Please take a look](https://developer.apple.com/bonjour/).

Comment: But does Bonjour work between Apple and Non-Apple devices?

Comment: [Looks like Android has it built-in](https://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/nsd.html). It also [exists for Windows](https://developer.apple.com/softwarelicensing/agreements/bonjour.php).

Comment: Nice. But fow I'll just stick to UDP `255.255.255.255`. Better technieuws will be implemented with time.